# Graphs and Kruskal's Algorithm - Python OOP

Tags: python, object-oriented, graph

This is my implementation of a graph and [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) in Python. I wanted to design the graph module myself and I would like some feedback on the design. I tried to follow [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) throughout. I am not sure if the separate Vertex object is wise, but I feel it could be useful as I expand this module.

I had a copy of a flowchart of Kruskal's algorithm from a textbook (not my current course) and I decided to implement it, I am wondering how Pythonic my code is.

I have also programmed Prim's algorithm in the same file but I will split it over two questions.

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Vertex {self.name}"

class Edge:
    def __init__(self, start, end, weight):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.weight = weight

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.start}{self.end}"

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, v, e):
        self.vertices = v
        self.edges = e

    def vertex_from_name(self, name):
        """ Return vertex object given vertex name. """
        return next((v for v in self.vertices if v.name == name), None)

    def add_edge(self, start, end, weight):
        """ Add an edge connecting two vertices. Arguments can either be vertex name or vertex object. """
        if isinstance(start, str):
            start = self.vertex_from_name(start)
        if isinstance(end, str):
            end = self.vertex_from_name(end)

        self.edges.append(Edge(start, end, weight))

    def edge_on_vertex(self, v):
        """ Return edges connected to given vertex v."""
        return [e for e in self.edges if (e.start == v) or (e.end == v)]

    def connected_vertices(self, v):
        """ Return the vertices connected to argument v."""
        if isinstance(v, str):
            v = self.vertex_from_name(v)

        return [e.start for e in self.edges if e.end == v] + [e.end for e in self.edges if e.start == v]

    def union(self, lst, e1, e2):
        """ Given a list of lists, merges e1 root list with e2 root list and returns merged list."""
        xroot, yroot = [], []
        # Find roots of both elements
        for i in lst:
            if e1 in i:
                xroot = i
            if e2 in i:
                yroot = i
        # Same root, cannot merge
        if xroot == yroot:
            return False
        xroot += yroot
        lst.remove(yroot)
        return lst

    def is_cycle(self):
        """ Return if the graph contains a cycle. """
        self.sets = [[v] for v in self.vertices]
        self._edges = sorted(self.edges, key=lambda x: x.weight)
        for e in self._edges:
            _temp = self.union(self.sets, e.start, e.end)
            if _temp == False:
                return True
            else:
                self.sets = _temp
        return False

    def Kruskals(self):
        """ Return MST using Kruskal's algorithm. """
        self.tree = Graph([], [])
        self.tree.vertices = self.vertices
        self.sorted_edges = sorted(self.edges, key=lambda x: x.weight)
        self.tree.edges.append(self.sorted_edges.pop(0))

        for edge in self.sorted_edges:
            self.tree.edges.append(edge)
            if self.tree.is_cycle():
                self.tree.edges.remove(edge)

        return self.tree

if __name__ == "__main__":
    v = [Vertex(x) for x in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]]

    g = Graph(v, [])

    g.add_edge("A", "B", 9)
    g.add_edge("A", "C", 12)
    g.add_edge("A", "D", 9)
    g.add_edge("A", "E", 11)
    g.add_edge("A", "F", 8)
    g.add_edge("B", "C", 10)
    g.add_edge("B", "F", 15)
    g.add_edge("C", "D", 8)
    g.add_edge("D", "E", 14)
    g.add_edge("E", "F", 12)

    print(g.Kruskals().edges)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Type hints

```
def __init__(self, start, end, weight):
```

can be

```
def __init__(self, start: Vertex, end: Vertex, weight: float):
```

depending on a few things, including the order of declaration of your classes, `Vertex` might need to be `'Vertex'` here.

For another example, this

```
def vertex_from_name(self, name):
```

can turn into

```
def vertex_from_name(self, name: str) -> Vertex:
```

### Efficient lookups

To make this more efficient:

```
    return next((v for v in self.vertices if v.name == name), None)
```

Consider maintaining a string-to-`Vertex` dictionary to reduce this lookup from O(n) to O(1) in time.

### Premature materialization

These:

```
    return [e for e in self.edges if (e.start == v) or (e.end == v)]


    return [e.start for e in self.edges if e.end == v] + [e.end for e in self.edges if e.start == v]
```

require that the entire results be stored to an in-memory list. To return the generator directly and reduce this memory requirement, the first one can be

```
    return (e for e in self.edges if v in {e.start, e.end})
```

and the second one can be

```
yield from (e.start for e in self.edges if e.end == v)
yield from (e.end for e in self.edges if e.start == v)
```

### Set-membership tests

This:

```
""" Given a list of lists, merges e1 root list with e2 root list and returns merged list."""
```

is probably better-expressed as accepting a list of `set`, not a list of `list`s. That will make these two tests:

```
        if e1 in i:
            xroot = i
        if e2 in i:
            yroot = i
```

faster. This:

```
    self.sets = [[v] for v in self.vertices]
```

would then become

```
    self.sets = [{v} for v in self.vertices]
```

### Strings as iterables

This

```
v = [Vertex(x) for x in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]]
```

can be

```
v = [Vertex(x) for x in 'ABCDEF']
```

### Convenience functions

Consider making a convenience function to turn this

```
g.add_edge("A", "B", 9)
g.add_edge("A", "C", 12)
g.add_edge("A", "D", 9)
g.add_edge("A", "E", 11)
g.add_edge("A", "F", 8)
g.add_edge("B", "C", 10)
g.add_edge("B", "F", 15)
g.add_edge("C", "D", 8)
g.add_edge("D", "E", 14)
g.add_edge("E", "F", 12)
```

into

```
g.add_edges(
    ("A", "B", 9),
    ("A", "C", 12),
    ("A", "D", 9),
    ("A", "E", 11),
    ("A", "F", 8),
    ("B", "C", 10),
    ("B", "F", 15),
    ("C", "D", 8),
    ("D", "E", 14),
    ("E", "F", 12),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Temporary state in `self`

`is_cycle` leaves `sets` and `_edges` in `self`. Not as a cache or as a result, but as temporary state which then leaks out, that is generally seen as a bad thing.

`Kruskals` leaves the `tree` in `self`, that's a bit more useful, but it could also be considered temporary state in `self`.

## The Algorithm

`union` doesn't look like an implementation of Union-Find to me. "Ask all sets whether the element is in them" is not how [`Find` normally works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Find). Despite that, it looks like something that reasonably should work, just slower.

The way `is_cycle` works means that the disjoint sets are built up from scratch (and the edges are re-sorted) every time `is_cycle` is called. That's wasteful, instead of rebuilding them from scratch, the sets could be kept up to date by unioning them as the main algorithm goes along. Calling `is_cycle` at all is wasteful: it loops over all edges, but the cycle could have been detected even before creating it by testing `Find(edge.start) != Find(edge.end)` in the main algorithm (`Kruskals`), which is how [the pseudocode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) does it.

Overall I think that makes the current algorithm take O(E²V log E) time, instead of O(E log E). Maybe not quite that, I just took the worst cases of all the nested loops, I didn't look at the effect of the number of sets decreasing as the algorithm progresses.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I will have to have a deeper look at Union-find and disjoint sets. One question: for the big O, what does V represent? Is it just another variable, independent of E?

Comment: @EugeneProut V is the number of vertices, E the number of edges. E cannot be greater than V² so they're not totally independent (every E could be replaced with V²), but using both V and E in the complexity analysis gives some idea of how the algorithm reacts to sparse graphs