# Prim's Algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, graph

**Prim's Algorithm**

This is an implementation of Prim's algorithm in Python. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm):

> 1. Initialize a tree with a single vertex, chosen arbitrarily from the graph.
> 2. Grow the tree by one edge: of the edges that connect the tree to vertices not yet in the tree, find the minimum-weight edge, and transfer it to the tree.
> 3. Repeat step 2 (until all vertices are in the tree).

**My code**

I have included the all the relevant sections for completeness but I want advice on the Prim's function inside the Graph class but feel free to comment on any part of the code!

I feel like the Prim's function can be improved as I have lots of conditionals that are similar but I don't know how to make it more Pythonic.

Any critique is welcome.

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Vertex {self.name}"

class Edge:
    def __init__(self, start, end, weight,directed):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.weight = weight
        self.directed = directed

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.start.name}{self.end.name}"

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, v, e):
        self.vertices = v
        self.edges = e

    def add_vertex(self, v):
        """ Add vertex of type Vertex. """
        self.vertices.append(v)

    def total_weight(self):
        """ Return total weight of all edges in graph."""
        return sum(e.weight for e in self.edges)

    def vertex_from_name(self, name):
        """ Return vertex object given vertex name. """

        return next((v for v in self.vertices if v.name == name), None)

    def add_edge(self, start, end, weight,directed=False):
        """ Add an edge connecting two vertices. Arguments can either be vertex name or vertex object. """
        if isinstance(start, str):
            start = self.vertex_from_name(start)
        if isinstance(end, str):
            end = self.vertex_from_name(end)

        self.edges.append(Edge(start, end, weight,directed))

    def add_edges(self,edges):
        for edge in edges:
            self.add_edge(edge[0],edge[1],edge[2])

    def edge_on_vertex(self, v):
        """ Return edges connected to given vertex v."""

        return (e for e in self.edges if v in {e.start, e.end})

    def connected_vertices(self, v):
        """ Return the vertices connected to argument v."""
        if isinstance(v, str):
            v = self.vertex_from_name(v)

        yield from (e.start for e in self.edges if e.end == v)
        yield from (e.end for e in self.edges if e.start == v)

    #Code to be reviewed
    def Prims(self, **kwargs):
        """ Return MST using Prim's algorithm. Optional argument is start vertex, defaults to first vertex. """
        self.start = kwargs.get('start', self.vertices[0])
        self.tree = Graph([], [])
        self.tree.vertices.append(self.start)

        while len(self.tree.vertices) != len(self.vertices):

            self.connected = set([e for vert in self.tree.vertices for e in self.edge_on_vertex(vert)])
            self.connected = sorted(list(self.connected), key=lambda x: x.weight)

            for edge in self.connected:
                if (edge.start not in self.tree.vertices) or (edge.end not in self.tree.vertices):
                    if edge.start in self.tree.vertices:
                        self.tree.add_vertex(edge.end)
                    else:
                        self.tree.add_vertex(edge.start)
                    self.tree.edges.append(edge)
                    break
        return self.tree


if __name__ == "__main__":
    v = [Vertex(x) for x in 'ABCDEF']

    g = Graph(v, [])

    g.add_edges((
        ("A", "B", 9),
        ("A", "C", 12),
        ("A", "D", 9),
        ("A", "E", 11),
        ("A", "F", 8),
        ("B", "C", 10),
        ("B", "F", 15),
        ("C", "D", 8),
        ("D", "E", 14),
        ("E", "F", 12),
    ))

    print([str(e) for e in g.Prims().edges])
```

**Code seem familiar?** This is a followup to [my earlier question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240343/graphs-and-kruskals-algorithm-python-oop/240352) about Kruskal's algorithm using the same module.

Comment: I see that you've called out a specific section of code to be reviewed. Keep in mind that CR policy encourages review of any part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

### Be consistent

- You named all your method functions with lowercase letters and separated the words with underscores... So maybe `Prims` should be named `prims` or `prim_algorithm`;
- In lists (argument lists, function calls, lists, etc) you always include a space after a comma (as you should), so do it always (I'm talking about `Edge.__init__`, `Graph.add_egde` and `Graph.add_edges`, for e.g.);
- For the simpler `Graph` methods, the one-liners, you have three lines: function definition, docstring, return statement; this is perfectly fine for simple functions. So you should also do it for `Graph.vertex_from_name`, instead of having a blank line between the docstring and the return.

### [Docstring conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

For [multiline docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings), consider having the final `"""` in a separate line, all by itself, and then include a blank line between the multiline docstring and the body of the function.

### Avoid long lines

[Python's style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests your lines don't exceed 81 characters (generally) and the [black code formatter](https://github.com/psf/black) goes with 89, because *"it's like highway speed limits, we won't bother you if you overdo it by a few km/h"*. But don't exceed that, no one wants to have to scroll right when reading someone else's code; for example, in your question, I have to scroll right to read some docstrings and some code in your functions.

### `Prims`

As for the `Prims` function itself, I would reformat the body slightly:

```py
def Prims(self, start=None):
    """ Return MST using Prim's algorithm.

    Optional argument `start` gives the start vertex (defaults to first vertex).
    """

    if start is None:
        start = self.vertices[0]
    self.tree = Graph([start], [])

    while len(self.tree.vertices) != len(self.vertices):

        self.connected = set([e for vert in self.tree.vertices for e in self.edge_on_vertex(vert)])
        self.connected = sorted(list(self.connected), key=lambda x: x.weight)

        for edge in self.connected:
            if (edge.start not in self.tree.vertices) or (edge.end not in self.tree.vertices):
                if edge.start in self.tree.vertices:
                    self.tree.add_vertex(edge.end)
                else:
                    self.tree.add_vertex(edge.start)
                self.tree.edges.append(edge)

                break

    return self.tree
```

- I reformatted the docstring to keep the first line short and to the point. A short first docstring line is very helpful because many IDEs can show it if you hover the function name when using it elsewhere. If the docstring is long and/or contains irrelevant information, you won't be able to read what you needed to recall what your function does.
- I added an explicit keyword argument, instead of having you guess what you decided the starting vertex argument was named; I also gave it a default value of `None`, against which I then compare to see if I need to use the default value. If you want that argument to always be called as a keyword argument, you can use this syntax: `def prims_algorithm(self, *, start=None):`.
- If `Graph` takes a list of vertices when creating a `Graph` instance, why don't you initialize your tree instance already with the starting vertex, instead of appending it right after instantiating the `Graph`?
- I added two blank lines by the end of the function to make it easier to spot the `return` and to make it easier to spot the `break`; in particular the `break` statement was fairly hard to find and a quick read didn't reveal it. I like having these important keywords visible!